# mobx react observer component isn't calling render after update

Tags: javascript, reactjs, mobx, mobx-react

**The requirement** is to:

> Toggle to open the rows component
>
> Highlight the selected row with a background color of cyan

However, when I click the toggle button, the App component isn't re-rendered :(

```
// App.js
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {observable, action } from 'mobx';
import {observer} from 'mobx-react';

@observer class Rows extends Component {
  rows() {
    let { store } = this.props;
    var rows = [];
    for (var i = 4; i > 0; i--) {
      rows.push(
        <div
          style={i == store.selectedRow ? { backgroundColor: "cyan" } : null }
          onClick={store.selectRow.bind(this, i)}>
          { i }
        </div>
      )
    }
    return rows;
  }
  render() {
    return (<div>{this.rows()}</div>);
  }
}

class Store {
  constructor(props) {
    this.selectRow = this.selectRow.bind(this)
    this.toggleSelector = this.toggleSelector.bind(this)
  }
  @observable showSelector = false;
  @observable selectedRow = 4;
  @action selectRow(n) {
    this.selectedVersion = n;
  }
  @action toggleSelector() {
    this.showSelector = !this.showSelector;
  }
}

//edit here
const store = new Store();

@observer class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <button onClick={store.toggleSelector}>Toggle Selector</button>
        { store.showSelector ? <Rows store={store}/> : null }
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

**EDIT** As per suggestions I've extracted the creation of the store outside of the component.

Comment: Don't create a new `store` in App's render. Create it outside of the class instead.

Comment: Doesn't change anything. Thank's for the suggestion though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Update: You can try to use `@action.bound` decorator, and skip `bind(this)` altogether in the constructor. My guess is manual binding is messing up the binding (no pun intended).

See [action.bound](https://mobx.js.org/refguide/action.html)

> The action decorator / function follows the normal rules for binding in javascript. However, Mobx 3 introduces action.bound to automatically bind actions to the targeted object. Note that unlike action, (@)action.bound does not take a name parameter, so the name will always be based on the property name to which the action is bound.

---

Your store is not being observed because it's created **inside** `render()`. You need to create the store and pass it down to your component either via `props` or MobX's [Provider](https://github.com/mobxjs/mobx-react#provider-and-inject).

> Provider is a component that can pass stores (or other stuff) using React's context mechanism to child components. This is useful if you have things that you don't want to pass through multiple layers of components explicitly.
>
> inject can be used to pick up those stores. It is a higher order component that takes a list of strings and makes those stores available to the wrapped component.

Comment: Defining it outside the component, even in it's only file doesn't change my output. Thanks for the suggestion though. Will try the provider.

Comment: Looks like provider is overkill for this solution. I will find it very helpful in my actual project though, thank you.

Comment: If you're interested in managing the component's internal state (i.e. state not shared with other component), you can simply use `Component.setState`.

Comment: My actual implementation has one store for 5+ components :( This the simplest example I could give.

Answer (score 0):

Try This.

```
// App.js
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {observable, action } from 'mobx';
import {observer} from 'mobx-react';

@observer class Rows extends Component {
  rows() {
    let { store } = this.props;
    var rows = [];
    for (var i = 4; i > 0; i--) {
      rows.push(
        <div
          style={i == store.selectedRow ? { backgroundColor: "cyan" } : null }
          onClick={store.selectRow.bind(this, i)}>
          { i }
        </div>
      )
    }
    return rows;
  }
  render() {
    return (<div>{this.rows()}</div>);
  }
}

class Store {
  constructor(props) {
    this.selectRow = this.selectRow.bind(this)
    this.toggleSelector = this.toggleSelector.bind(this)
  }
  @observable showSelector = false;
  @observable selectedRow = 4;
  @action selectRow(n) {
    this.selectedVersion = n;
  }
  @action toggleSelector() {
    this.toggleSelector = !this.showSelector;
  }
}

// defined outside
const store = new Store();

@observer class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <button onClick={store.toggleSelector}>Toggle Selector</button>
        { store.showSelector ? <Rows store={store}/> : null }
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

Comment: Nope. Defining it outside, even in it's only file doesn't change my output. Thanks for the suggestion though.